# Add Answer From Top in iOS App

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, ios-app

When there's one answer, it's no big deal. But when there's dozens and you have to scroll past every single other answer to add a new one, loading them in batches on a sketchy network, that takes **a lot** longer than it should.

When already on the Answers tab, display a <kbd>+</kbd> button to add an answer.

[image]

Comment: It's the same on Android app. I think it has something to do with UI consistency with PC version where answer box is at the bottom. I really approve this feature request though, since mobile UI should be designed for mobile.

Comment: Thanks. It works on desktop because you can, for instance, drag the scroll bar down. And there's pagination with a lot of answers. But **Infinite scroll + footer = bad UX**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current behavior here is deliberate.

You shouldn't post an answer to something unless you've read the other answers, how else would you know if someone's already posted your answer or not? While I'm all for encouraging more content creation from the mobile applications it doesn't make much sense to do that with the risk of degrading quality.

The only case I can really see this being useful is when posting on [the formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox). It is however important to note that the website remedies this slightly by having pagination of answers rather than infinite scrolling. I don't necessarily think this is a huge problem but we can consider doing only one page of infinite scrolling them showing "Load More" buttons for answers in the applications.

For now however, this is going to be a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: I was a fan of this request, but your your point about reading other answers first makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Joe I was a fan of it too until I asked why we weren't doing it on the websites too :)

Comment: I can appreciate the concern for quality **(+1)**. I would however offer up the anecdote of having read the answers, leaving, doing research, formulating an answer, and coming back to write it. This happened to me on a featured meta question, where the time between reading answers and writing my own was hours. It took minutes on my phone to get to the button, 
when on the desktop it would take all of three seconds

Comment: @mhlester Who's to say another answer hasn't been added which covers everything you've found in your research in that time?

Comment: I think the real issue is the time it takes to scroll through answers on the app, rather than where the button is placed.

Comment: If I've already favorited the question, which in this case I had.

Comment: Would you consider giving it a second look Kasra? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253541/248072

Comment: @mhlester it's a really tough call. I can easily see how in some cases, that one included, it'd be very helpful. I really don't want to encourage the behavior though... maybe we can do something like "only show it if there's more than N answers"... I'll need to think about this more and talk to the team.

Comment: I appreciate the consideration. It felt like a compelling case this latest post.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi and a [third look](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280419/do-i-really-need-to-scroll-through-1000-answers)? :-)

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Please consider 'more than N answers' because as you said -- on desktop view you don't force users to see every answer so why should you on mobile. As I said for people who are primarily on Code Golf where reading prior answers is absolutely not necessary-- it's a big deal if the question is very popular or you want to post new challenges to the sandbox like me.