# "Add an answer" short cut

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Would it be possible to add another "Add to answer" button directly after the question on the mobile app? After browsing the [new profile thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253450/259198), I had to scroll past 51 one answers so I could add my bug finding.

I guess it makes sense to force people to scroll through answers so they could see them and avoid duplicates, but it seems counterintuitive when there are questions like these.

[image: Scrolling past 51 answers]