# Do I really need to scroll through 1000 answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, ios-app

EDIT: Apparently someone has brought this up before [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222344/306202), dating back to 2014. It was status declined because 'you should read all answers before answering' and 'Sandbox questions' like what I am talking about are edge cases to the system. Well I would disagree that on sites like Code Golf that gets well received with answers you absolutely don't need to read the other answers and some questions get a *lot* of answers.. so for basically any question on Code Golf we're forcing this bad functionality. I would like to revisit the issue if possible.

I was on Code Golf meta using the iOS app and was going to post a proposed challenge in the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/45348). I couldn't find how to add an answer.

I realized its at the very bottom of every other answer, checked by going to another question.

[image]

So do I really need to scroll through 1000+ answers before I can add my own? Is there no way to add an answer without scrolling to the absolute bottom? Should there be a way to if there's not? As it is I would be scrolling for a while..

For the record I don't just 'go into desktop mode on Chrome' because I actually prefer using the mobile app for writing questions and answers especially with the recently added functionality making drafts easier. Also I know the buttons in the top right go to the next and previous question. It doesn't change anything except for asking then 'do I need to tap 1000 times'. Disclaimer: this question was wrote with the iOS app.

Comment: And how it's not, @cat? What would you propose instead?

Comment: @cat the answer to "Do I really have to scroll through 1000 answers?" is: "Yes, you have". And this is already tagged as feature request asking for a "way to add an answer without scrolling to the absolute bottom" (quoted from the question). The other question I found propose exactly such a thing, with an official SE response explaining why one have to scroll through all answers.